# WPF - Items Collection Dynamic Margins

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i want to render several elements inside a full width border and to compute programmatically margins so i get rectangles in a grid with appropriate margins. This would be the rendering that i want to get:

[image]

The margins should be computed using an algorithm based on the data-bound values. To explain the idea, let's assume i have a list of strings containing "One", "Two" and "Three" that i am binding to my control. Let's assume my algorithm is very simple and assigns +100 to each next element margin. So i would have three rectangles:

- Rectangle for element "One" - Margin: 100
- Rectangle for element "Two" - Margin: 200
- Rectangle for element "Three" - Margin: 300

All the rectangles are the same, the only difference is the computed margin.

My initial idea was to use an ItemsControl and use a MultiBinding to compute the margins for each element.

However, when i use an ItemsControl with a MultiBinding to compute the Dynamic Margin, i can't get the rectangles to render properly.

```
 <ItemsControl>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="sys:String" 
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
                        <sys:String>One</sys:String>
                        <sys:String>Two</sys:String>
                        <sys:String>Three</sys:String>
                    </x:Array>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle Name="InnerRectangle" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Blue" Width="2" Height="120">
                                <Rectangle.Margin>
                                    <MultiBinding Mode="OneWay" Converter="{StaticResource MultiMarginConverter}">
                                        <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}"></Binding>
                                        <Binding Path=""></Binding>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </Rectangle.Margin>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

If i run this, the margins compute correctly in the converter, but the rectangles render as stacked on top of each other?

The algorithm to compute the margins will use several values from the current context, so i need to use several property values, and that is why i use a multi-binding.

Here is the converter just to get some dynamic margins for the sake of trying out the concept:

```
 public class MultiBindingMarginConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    List<Double> margins = new List<Double>() { 110, 220, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777 };

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var randomizer = new Random();;

        // I just get a random margin to try the concept. The margin will be computed by a more complex algorithm
        var computedMargin = margins.ElementAt(randomizer.Next(1, 7));

        return new Thickness(computedMargin, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Note: When i just run the app it doesn't render the rectangles properly. However, when i debug and set a breakpoint in the multibinding converter, the margins get applied and the rectangles render correctly?!

I think the general approach should work, but i can't figure out what i am doing wrong in the rendering that would cause the rectangles to render with the wrong margins, even if they are computed correctly in the converter.

Thanks

Comment: I'm with @Clemens on possibly misunderstanding your question. How about this, can you just show a quick-n-dirty mock picture of what you're trying to accomplish? I may be mistaken but it sounds like the effect you're after is probably far less complicated than it's being made to be. :/

Comment: There is an image of the rendering i am trying to accomplish. It looks simple. I just want to set dynamic left margins on the blue rectangle elements instead of fixing them, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I correctly understood your question, but in case you wanted to put all those Rectangles into the *same* Grid cell you would have to set the ItemsControl's [ItemsPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) to a Grid:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Grid/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

---

Similarly you may also use a Canvas as ItemsPanel and set the `Canvas.Left` property (instead of `Margin`) on each item Rectangle.

Comment: y.. i will try to use a canvas.. i added an example in my explanation which should help to understand what i want to accomplish

Comment: The Canvas approach worked. The margins get rendered properly. However, i am still not clear why the previous approach wasn't working.